# Is there an easier way to solve the given problem?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics, factoring

If $x + 2 + \sqrt{3}i=0$ then find the value of $2x^4+3x^3-x^2-15x+36$

If you try to find the values of $x^2, x^3 $and $ x^4$, and then put the values in, we can find the solution to be 1. But is there a better way to solve this problem? Where you can probably break the second polynomial into a simple one and then solve it, saving a lot of time and making the calculations less prone to errors?

Comment: $x$ id four time a simple root if unit. Therefore powers Can be easily computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real coefficients in the quartic inspired me to multiply $x + 2 + \sqrt{3}i\;$ by the conjugate, which gives

$$(x + 2 + \sqrt{3}i)(x + 2 - \sqrt{3}i)=x^2+4x+7.$$

Dividing the given expression by $x^2+4x+7$ (just to see if we get a simple form) leads to $$2x^4+3x^3-x^2-15x+36=\underbrace{(x^2+4x+7)}_{0}\cdot(2x^2-5x+5)+1$$
Yes, if  $x + 2 + \sqrt{3}i=0\;$ then $2x^4+3x^3-x^2-15x+36=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that:

$$-2-\sqrt{3}i=\left|-2-\sqrt{3}i\right|\exp\left(\arg\left(-2-\sqrt{3}i\right)i\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{\left(-2\right)^2+\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)^2}\exp\left(\left(\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)i\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{7}\exp\left(\left(\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)i\right)\tag1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x+2=-\sqrt{3}i$$
Squaring,
$$x^2 +4x+4=-3$$
Or,
$$x^2+4x+7=0\Rightarrow (x^2+4x+7)^2=0$$
Open the brackets and use to simplify.